# how to use $apply and $watch in Angularjs 1.4.10 Directive Structure like this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

```
`.directive('counter', function counter() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      count: '='
    },
    controller: function () {
      function increment() {
        this.count++;
      }
      function decrement() {
        this.count--;
      }
      this.increment = increment;
      this.decrement = decrement;
    },
    controllerAs: 'counter',
    template: [
      '<div class="todo">',
        '<input type="text" ng-model="counter.count">',
        '<button type="button" ng-click="counter.decrement();">-</button>',
        '<button type="button" ng-click="counter.increment();">+</button>',
      '</div>'
    ].join('')
  };
});
```

`

[For Reference I tried to pass $apply in toddmotto jsfiddle but it can't executed](https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/avdezer7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=avdezer7)

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are needing to do with those methods but you need to inject `$scope` into the directive controller in order to use them.

This is the same  as for a regular `angular.module('').controller`

```
controller: function ($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      ...

     $scope.$watch(function(){
          return vm.someProp;
      }, function(newVal,oldVal){
          // watch code
     });
    ....
```

Comment: @charlietfi I tried this thing I also mentioned in question. But it didn't work...

Comment: create demo where it isn't working. Demo link you provided doesn't inject `$scope` or show an watch